# grouping multiple rows by id and timedate and display it based on date

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have a table:

[image]

and I want to display it like this one

```
id_pasien kunjungan
 193      2018-02-23
 193      2018-02-24
```

I've made this code but I don't know how to group it by timedate and display it like what I want above

```
public function record_Odontogram($id_pasiens){
    $query = "SELECT id_pasien, 
              GROUP_CONCAT(inserted_at) as kunjungan 
              FROM odontogram WHERE id_pasien=$id_pasien AND YourDate >= dateadd(day,datediff(day,1,GETDATE()),0)
    AND YourDate < dateadd(day,datediff(day,0,GETDATE()),0) ";
    $res = $this->db->query($query);
    return $res;
}
```

Comment: your query seems to be incomplete

Comment: @Vickel  just edit it

Comment: why are you using GROUP_CONCAT?

Comment: @tyro what should I used then ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inorder to group by date, use DATE():

```
$query = "SELECT id_pasien, DATE(inserted_at) as kunjungan 
          FROM odontogram 
          WHERE ...
          GROUP BY DATE(inserted_at) ";
```

Answer (score 1):

Use below Query

SELECT id_pasien, DATE_FORMAT(inserted_at, '%Y-%m-%d') as kunjungan FROM odontogram WHERE id_pasien=193 group by kunjungan asc